# What is the zero condition in linear regression?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

hypothesis is given as `h theta(x) = theta0 + theta1x` , in other words y is a linear function of x .

theta0 is zero condition.

What is the meaning of term zero condition ?

Comment: This may need more context. Looks like that it is a synonym for offset, but not sure.

Comment: In the standard sense, that is just the equation of a straight line (y = mx + c) for your linear regression. For example, regression against product cost (y) and the number of additional features the product contains (x) could be studied by linear regression. However, a product with zero additional features has a non-zero baseline cost. The zero condition allows x = 0 to have a y = non-zero value.

Comment: @roganjosh makes sense now, thanks. I think the hypothesis is represented as : y  =  c + mx .

Comment: @blue-sky absolutely, I was just presenting the linear equation in the standard format. I was reluctant to put this straight as an answer because I wasn't sure if there was some context I was not seeing as cel pointed out. I will present in an answer so that this question is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard sense, that is just the equation of a straight line (y = c + mx) for your linear regression. For example, regression against product cost (y) and the number of additional features the product contains (x) could be studied by linear regression. However, a product with zero additional features has a non-zero baseline cost. The zero condition allows x = 0 to have a y = non-zero value.